# BOUNDP checks free variables in PROGV?

Tags: common-lisp

Suppose both `a` and `b` are unbound (i.e. `(notany #'boundp '(a b))` => `T`), then this works as expected:

```lisp
(progv '(a b) '(1)
  (boundp 'a)) ; => T
```

Then `PROGV` entry in CLHS states:

> If too few values are supplied, the remaining symbols are bound and then made to have no value.

which contradicts what I see in REPL:

```lisp
(progv '(a b) '(1)
  (boundp 'b)) ; => NIL
```

I'll expect `(boundp 'b)` to return `T`.

Question: Did I misunderstand the wordings in CLHS? Or is it a bug in SBCL?

Environment:
SBCL 2.2.10, Linux x86_64

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the wording in the standard is poor, but what is intended to happen is that

```
(progv '(a b) '(1) ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
(progv '(a b) '(1 nil)
  (makunbound 'b)
  ...)
```

This is very different than simply not binding `b` at all as you can see by considering this:

```
(progv '(b) '(3)
  (progv '(b) '()
    ... b unbound here ...)
  (symbol-value 'b))
```

which evaluates to `3`.  The issue is that `makunbound` removes the value of the dynamic binding of the symbol that is currently in scope.  In a shallow binding implementation that's the same thing as simply marking the value cell of the symbol as having no value, because the outer value will be restored in due course.  But in a deeply bound implementation the binding must still exist in the stack of bindings, but its value must be marked as 'unbound' somehow.

Perhaps the problem, really, is that `boundp` and `makunbound` at least are arguably misnamed: `boundp` really tells you if the current dynamic binding of a symbol has a value, not if one exists at all, and `makunbound` removes the value from the current dynamic binding.  But these names were inherited by CL.  There is no way of telling (and probably should be no way) whether there *is* a current non-global dynamic binding for a symbol or not.

Finally, this behaviour of `progv` is useful because it means you can say

```
(progv '(a b c) '()
  ... now I know a, b, c are unbound ...)
```

which means you can avoid the problem that somebody might have polluted the environment in ways you can't control.

Comment: Cool thanks! I didn't get further than `makunbound`. That makes it more clear!

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense! Really didn't expect the `makunbound` aspect of `progv`. I don't see problems with `boundp` and `makunbound` though. Small corrections to your third example: quote your `(3)` and use `(symbol-value 'b)` to retrieve dynamic value of `b`.

Comment: @zacque thanks, I've fixed it.  Will teach me to try to write a program without a lisp implementation to hand.

Answer (score 1):

It states first bound but then made having no value (means not even `NIL` as a value - what I think you expect - me too, because that would be the behavior in lambda lists e.g.). So then `b` must be unbound after binding (like `(makunbound 'b)`). Only after being unbound, variable `b` would have no value.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. First, what does "having no value" mean in CL? If it is the value of `(values)`, then it doesn't explain `(progv '(a) (list (values)) (boundp 'a))` evaluating to `T`. Second, I'm evaluating `(boundp 'b)` in the dynamic environment of `PROGV`. So it's not being "unbound after binding".

Comment: it means that it is `unbound`. - Okay given it would bound as you say - which value you expect then to be bound to `b`?

Comment: The citation says: `If too few values are supplied, the remaining symbols are bound and then made to have no value.` - they should have said instead of `made to have no value` => `unbound again`.

Comment: Your interpretation of the cited statement seems like a stretch, though it explains the current state of affair. If "remaining symbols are bound and then made to have no value" means "left unbound like in DEFVAR without initial value", then it could have said so in a straightforward manner. My interpretation of the statement comes in two parts: first they are bound, so BOUNDP should return T doesn't matter what value they're assigned to; then they are assigned to no value (whatever "no value" means).

Comment: Yes, I think the text in that part is not well written. The person should have use other words to make it clear.

In `R`, a totally different language, "no value" would mean to assign `NULL`. In CL, I guess the equivalent would be to make it unbound. assigning NIL would not do it becuase NIL would be then a value (remember `NIL == ()`).